# Can I stay in my girlfriend's council flat during the time I visit her?

Tags: uk, visa-free-entry, proof-of-accommodation

I am a US citizen, and I am attempting to visit my UK girlfriend visa-free for ten days. She has invited me to stay at hers and I have enough money to support myself during the vacation. However, I wasn't sure whether the fact that she lives in council housing would be acceptable by UKVI, regardless of whether she has invited me to stay. Should I book a hotel for myself instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes you can stay with her without any issue.**

There's no reason why council housing would be relevant to the UKVI. The rules for non-visa visits are as follows:

> - they must not work during their stay in the UK (although study is    permitted as a 'student visitor'), with limited exceptions for
>     authorized "permitted paid engagements" of up to one month
> - they    must not register a marriage or register a civil partnership during    their stay in the UK
> - they must present evidence of sufficient money to    fund their stay in the UK (if requested by the border inspection    officer)
> - they must intend to leave the UK at the end of their visit and    can meet the cost of the return/onward journey
> - if under the    age of 18, they can demonstrate evidence of suitable care    arrangements and parental (or guardian's) consent for
>     their stay in    the UK

Since you're not coming to study, work or stay for more than 6 months [you're within your rights](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/usa/family) to stay anywhere you are welcome.

Similarly, your girlfriend is within her rights to have overnight visitors in her home, especially as only for ten nights. As long as she "makes sure that anyone living at or visiting the property does not cause a nuisance".

Even as just an introductory tenant, the main things she can't do are:

> - swap your home by mutual exchange
> - apply to buy your home
> - take in lodgers or sublet any part of your home
> - use your home for business
> - make major improvement to your home

Answer (score 5):

For a **visa application**, this would be complicated. If you were relying on her hospitality as a premise for the visa, you'd need to provide documentary evidence that her council is okay with her having boarders.

However, since you're entering **visa-free**, you're not going to be subject to as exhaustive a check at the border as a visa process would be. If you arrive with definite plans to return after 10 days (and return tickets booked, which the airline will have informed about through advance passenger information) and you make a reasonably non-destitute impression when you approach the immigration booth, it is pretty unlikely that they will take the time to inquire in detail about the sleeping arrangements.

For her own sake, your girlfriend should still *investigate* before your visit whether her lease allows her to have someone living with her for that amount of time. Depending on the precise rules she's renting under, her rates *might* be predicated on the size or total income of her household, and you'll want to be sure that your temporary presence is not going to upset that calculus.

You'll then know whether you need to book a hotel. And in the unlikely case that you're asked about it at the border, you can then say, yes we checked that and it turns out to be okay. Problem solved.

Comment: As far as I have read, council housing does not impose any limitations on having someone living with you temporarily. Even renting out rooms is allowed:
https://www.gov.uk/council-housing/types-of-tenancy

Comment: "it is pretty unlikely that they will take the time to inquire in detail about the sleeping arrangements" oh my god I just now found out they have scrapped landing cards

Comment: I *just* found out they opened the ePassport gates to US citizens as of eight days ago... is this question even relevant now?

Comment: @user25366 It's still possible for you to be rejected from the ePassport gates and questioned.

Comment: sorry, bit of a digression but got through the e gates no problem and my gf is my fiancee now